# Finding a memory leak

Tags: c#

I have an issue with the following code. I create a memory stream in the GetDB function and the return value is used in a *using* block. For some unknown reason if I dump my objects I see that the MemoryStream is still around at the end of the Main method. This cause me a massive leak. Any idea how I can clean this buffer ?

I have actually checked that the Dispose method has been called on the MemoryStream  but the object seems to stay around, I have used the diagnostic tools of Visual Studio 2017 for this task.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<CsvProduct> products;
        using (var s = GetDb())
        {
            products = Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CsvProduct>>(s).ToList();
        }
    }

    public static Stream GetDb()
    {
        var filepath = Path.Combine("c:/users/tom/Downloads", "productdb.zip");
        using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(filepath))
        {
            var data = archive.Entries.Single(e => e.FullName == "productdb.json");
            using (var s = data.Open())
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                s.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return (Stream)ms;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't return `ms`, return `ms.ToArray()`. Also, I don't see where you're disposing the MemoryStream. You should put it in a `using` statement.

Comment: @itsme86 It's disposed in `Main()` (got me too)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You're right, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Disposing something just means, that the garbage collector is allowed to clean up. Not that it is cleaned up.

Comment: _I see that the MemoryStream is still around_ - How did you check that?

Comment: "Disposed" is not the same as "GC has collected it"

Comment: @itsme86 there's no need to create an extra array here; returning the `MemoryStream` is fine - personally I'd prefer to just return the raw inner stream and uncompress on the fly, but then you'd need to figure out how to wrap that so that both are disposed together

Comment: It's up for debate whether this should be classified as a *memory leak*. The application allocates memory for the stream and keeps it around after the object has been disposed. That in itself is not an issue. What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: My main issue is memory consumption . It looks that my application is consuming a lot of memory and I try to figure out what is wrong . The MemoryStream i am using   is 600M and even if I GC.Collect() it does not go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For some unknown reason if I dump my objects I see that the MemoryStream is still around at the end of the Main method.

That isn't particuarly abnormal; GC happens separately.

> This cause me a massive leak.

That isn't a leak, it is just memory usage.

> Any idea how I can clean this buffer ?

I would probably just *not use a `MemoryStream`*, instead returning something that wraps the live uncompressing stream (from `s = data.Open()`). The *problem* here, though, is that you can't *just* return `s` - as `archive` would still be disposed upon leaving the method. So if I needed to solve this, I would create a custom `Stream` that wraps an inner stream and which disposes a second object when disposed, i.e.

```
class MyStream : Stream {
    private readonly Stream _source;
    private readonly IDisposable _parent;
    public MyStream(Stream, IDisposable) {...assign...}

    // not shown: Implement all Stream methods via `_source` proxy

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        _source.Dispose();
        _parent.Dispose();
    }
}
```

then have:

```
public static Stream GetDb()
{
    var filepath = Path.Combine("c:/users/tom/Downloads", "productdb.zip");
    var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(filepath);
    var data = archive.Entries.Single(e => e.FullName == "productdb.json");
    var s = data.Open();
    return new MyStream(s, archive);
}
```

(could be improved slightly to make sure that `archive` is disposed if an exception happens before we return with success)

Comment: Any exceptions opening the second stream result in the first being leaked without being disposed of.

Comment: @Servy I believe I remarked on that in the parentheses

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks,  it works . I think I have some stuffs I don't get right with the Disposable pattern. It sounds me a little bit longer to create an inherited class everytime I nest different disposable object. I thought that GC would have properly clean in a timely manner all the disposed object (I have done a test with GC.Collect & GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers and the memorystream was still hanging around).

Comment: @Dave IDisposable doens't impact GC; the thing we're changing here is: not reading the entire stream into a `byte[]` (ala `MemoryStream`) - it is *that* that is causing problems; large arrays go on the "large object heap", which has much slower collection semantics

Comment: @MarcGravell: It is very intersting it solves my issue but I still doesn't get the details . I have a related  issue where now i have 3 levels of nesting (blobstorage/ziparchive/stream) . Should I create a new MyStream class with 3 fields for each of these disposable objects ?

Comment: @Dave if that works for you, sure; the "details" is that a `Stream` is *meant* to be a "hose", not a "bucket" - i.e. we don't have all the data yet - just a mechanism to get data on demand; by copying everything into a `MemoryStream`, you're creating a "bucket" i.e. "here's all that data in one place". That obviously impacts memory usage.